# Meta-cat program

Tags: code-golf, string, code-generation, metagolf, test-battery

Write a program or function that takes input and outputs/returns a full program (in the same language) that outputs said input.
Note that the input may contain any printable ASCII character or newline (AKA 0x20-0x7f and 0x0a). However, the input will not have trailing whitespace nor preceding whitespace, nor will it be empty.

### Test cases (Javascript):

```
cat => console.log("cat")
fish => console.log("fish")
m(newline)ta-c t => console.log("m\neta-c t") 
m"'`\c => console.log("m\"'`\\c")
```

### Example program

```js
function metaCat(text){
  return "console.log(\"" + text.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\").replace(/"/g,"\\\"").replace(/\n/g,"\\n") + "\")"
}
```

### Scoring

Score is the sum of your code size and the size of the output for each test case

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't been asked yet

Comment: `0x7f` isn't printable ASCII, I'm assuming that's a half-open range?

Comment: @Neil thats what was in most other questions, so probably?

Comment: Should we count the trailing newlines of our output programs? In your example with JS, the `console.log(...)` will also output a trailing newline. Does this mean [the score is 90](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNFNSkxKzdHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP11DKTmxREmTC0UoLbM4A10sNyYvtSRRN1kBqFoBXUpJPSEmJhmo5f9/AA) + whatever the size of your original program? Or would it be 86 instead?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen if the trailing newline does not matter for the code to be correct, and there's one no matter the input, then you don't have to count it.

Comment: do we need to handle empty input?

Comment: @c-- no, you dont

Comment: @Dadsdy Can you specify that in the question?

Answer (score 12):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 78 + 2109 = 2187 bytes

```
+++++[>+++++++++<-]>[->+>>+>++>+>++<<<<<<]>-->>+>+>>+++<<<<,[[-<.>]>[.>]<[<],]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYpBCoAgEEX3niLctBinEwxzkVHIBElCF2XnNxV6fP7i8Y7bpxLfcLUGA2H4IXQsyMB9APNo4hhxSh7xMEYEaePe9yMhZ1xrwVcV03MqnW2pHsOiVdbrbsMH)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 19 (program) + 60 (output) = 79 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to loopy walt*

```python
"print(%r)".__mod__
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RU5BCsIwELznFcuCmKIVjyL0Ja3EEBNaaLelWQWPvsNLQPQDvsbfmJiDp5nZnRnm_pqu3I4UHq5qnmd25e6N09wRy8Vc4EapYTwplT-fG1vPymhvPVRQo9GMa0DX-Tbh0BDr0sDviDjg8tiYSA6Con0r3DhDCkNH8G_aC0htTiZVCLAX3UsfCcGqgt5SEnkSFXlICBm_)

Comment: `"print(%r)".__mod__` is a bit shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes + 23 character sum = 26 score

```
øDṪ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJBIiwiIiwiw7hE4bmqIiwiIiwiY2F0XG5maXNoXG5cIm1cXG50YS1jIFwiXG5tXCInYFxcYyJd)

So funny story, my previous answer wasn't actually valid because `øD` already wraps in quotes, making the `q` useless.

### Explained

```
øDṪ
øD  # dictionary compress the input, quoting it at the same time
  Ṫ # Remove the trailing backtick
```

Answer (score 4):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 1 + 32 = 33 bytes

```
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/P@H//@TEEgA)

The outputs are:

```
"cat"
"fish"
"m\nta-c t"
"m\"'`\\c"
```

Answer (score 4):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 71 + 46 bytes = 117

<sup>Hover over any symbol to see what it does</sup>

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiXCI8bz4nXCJpOjAoP3Y6XFxcbjwgXFwgPm88XCInXCJ+PCB8LiEwNVxuXnY/PSBcIidcIjp2Pz1hL1xuXiAgXCInYSdcIn4vXG5+L14xXCInZDMqJ1wiIiwiaW5wdXQiOiInYWJjICdcIiBkZWYiLCJzdGFjayI6IiIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyJ9)

Unformatted version if the code above appears glitched:

```
"<o>'"i:0(?v:\
< \ >o<"'"~< |.!05
^v?= "'":v?=a/
^  "'a'"~/
~/^1"'d3*'"
```

Only characters that need escaping are the single quote and line break

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 24 + 76 = 100 bytes

```haskell
f=("main=putStr"++).show
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8GCpaUlaboWO9JsNZRyEzPzbAtKS4JLipS0tTX1ijPyyyHSN7tLUotLkhOLU4sVbBWilZITS5R0FJTSMoszQHRuTF5Jom6yQgmEo6SeEBOTrBTLxQUyEaghJZ9LQQFisE-egopCmoJSBtDyfCVUYZB9IKo0F0jmJhYoaOSk5qWXZCjoKaRpKsBdAHESzOUA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 51 bytes + 110 bytes = 161 bytes

```rust
fn f(x:&str){print!("fn main(){{print!({:?})}}",x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7RCsIwDEXf9xUxA21g@gHzwQ9xomVYLNhM2giD0m@vXcHm5ZITODf@GyRnw2DUOu6DeIofb1l2Cgt02rKi@EdxvCRKCYeVUm5niB2UMYuHAJbhirMWHACNDa8tnZqYRB9n2LDv0eFhmh/Y305Fu9ytPH3TVJUKdG5bLX9z@QipwtSl/AM)

We take the input as a string, but print the output, saving having to specify `f`'s return type. `Debug` does the escaping for us.

Comment: 40 bytes as an expression: `|x|print!("fn main(){{print!({:?})}}",x)`

Answer (score 4):

#### Common Lisp, 21 + 52 = 73

```
(lambda(s)`(print,s))
```

For example:

```
(funcall (lambda(s)`(print,s)) "cat"))
=> (print "cat")
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 23+49 = 72 bytes

```bash
printf 'echo %q\n' "$1"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifpqFZ/b@gKDOvJE1BPTU5I19BtTAmT11BScVQ6X8tV1p@kUKFQmaeQnJiiUJaZnGGgop6bkxeSaJuskKJOoijFGNgYp4Qk6xuXa2QBtRWoWSdWpaYA2RpQLiaSta1XP8B)

Answer (score 3):

## [ForWhile](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ForWhile), 42 (Program) + (9+10+14+14) (Output) = 89 bytes

`` 34#::`[_~:[~;;=[92#):92=[:#)#])#"(,#)"(,#) ``

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=forwhile&src=MzQjOjpgW19-Olt-Ozs9WzkyIyk6OTI9WzojKSNdKSMiKCwjKSIoLCMp&in=IjEyM1w0CjU2NyI=)

## Explanation:

ForWhile allows multi-line strings, so the only characters that need to be escaped are `"` and `\`

```
34#                                         \ print a "
   ::`[                                     \ loop up to 34^34 times (for-while has no infinite loops)
       _                                    \ read a character
        ~:[~                                \ character is not end-of file
            ;;=[92#)                        \ print a backslash if character is "
                    :92=[:#)                \ print a backslash if character is \
                            #               \ print the character
                             ])             \ break loop if character was end of file
                               #"(,#)"(,#)  \ print "(,#) to print the string produced by the program
```

The printed programs are just a (multi-line) string literal containing the Input-string, followed by `(,#)` which will print the string.

Output for Test-cases:

```
"cat"(,#)

"fish"(,#)

"m
ta-c t"(,#)

"m\"'`\\c"(,#)
```

## ForWhile,  35 (Program) + (4*17+3+4+8+6) (Output) = 124 bytes

Shorter program but slightly longer output.

`` "17-9:`[1-:@:[#])?"(,#)9:`[_~:[~#]) ``

Prints a program (of length 17) that prints all its source code except the first 17 characters and then terminates, followed by the input string.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 32 + 60 = 92 bytes

```javascript
s=>`print(${JSON.stringify(s)})`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3NCsIwEITvfYolCKZoi0ehpDcvHvTQoxUaYtJGYlOapaClz14TxZ/DsszM7jdXPnAnet1hMmxnxWbH8qrrdYt0Me6L4yF16FWt1Z26eIqr2UgEtMhNoR8SGGyy6AREcCRrIEq7Juxb2SJPBOBbkGVVloLAOUqV7XdcNNQBy2GMAAJP2EtAKV@ReeuHX7FXlhrZ1tiETNjWWeMdW9MQvR7kwM1HTX7@j76wOJuf)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 108 + 84 = 192 bytes

Lots of bytes less thanks to @c--.

```c
f(int*s){for(printf("main(){puts(\"");*s;s++)printf(*s-34?*s-92?*s-10?s:"\\n":"\\\\":"\\\"");puts("\");}");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYw/D4IwEMVn@ynwprakjf8WZWAzDo4mLhcTAtSQYEs4dCF89tqCcbh3d@/u/Ur1LEvvDW/sIEmMxvW868NiOLyKxnIxdu@BOAKITFJGaSp@d0lqf8iDHndRt5ucToBoISri0mJsBgCGaYrlQzqZ2R/XVIKNbGX4FW41DYnWOrwsxqVuW4f27vq2Wv9dbZSmqpDnB0Yim/wX)

Comment: [this](https://tio.run/##PYw/D4IwEMVn@ynwprakjf8WZWAzDo4mLhcTAtSQYEs4dCF89tqCcbh3d@/u/Ur1LEvvDW/sIEmMxvW868NiOLyKxnIxdu@BOAKITFJGaSp@d0lqf8iDHndRt5ucToBoISri0mJsBgCGaYrlQzqZ2R/XVIKNbGX4FW41DYnWOrwsxqVuW4f27vq2Wv9dbZSmqpDnB0Yim/wX) produces much shorter output, which reduces the score significantly

Comment: You're supposed the add the output lengths to the score.

Comment: @xigoi My bad, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 30 bytes, score 82

```lua
print(('print%q'):format(...))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQx1Mqxaqa1ql5RflJpZo6OnpaWr@//8/V0k9ISYZAA)

No need for parentheses in resulting program since we're printing a string literal.

Answer (score 3):

## [owl lisp](https://haltp.org/posts/owl.html), 51 + 176 = 227

this is a very *quick and dirty* solution

```scheme
(λ (s) `(print (list->string ',(string->list s))))
```

example:

```scheme
> (eval ((λ (s) `(print (list->string ',(string->list s)))) "cat") *toplevel*)
cat
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 + 28 = 30

```
Ṙṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOSU5OCVFMSVCOSVBQiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PWNhdCUwQWZpc2glMEElMjJtJTVDbnRhLWMlMjB0JTIyJTBBbSUyMiclNjAlNUNjJmZsYWdzPVY=)

Take the string `Ṙ`epresentation, then remove the `ṫ`ail (last character, the end quote).

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 9 bytes, score 39

```
¶
$¶
^
K`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz//9A2LhUgjuPyTvj/P5crtSRRN1mhBAA) Explanation:

```
¶
$¶
```

Change newlines into pilcrows.

```
^
K`
```

Prepend the `K` instruction (replace buffer with literal string).

The test cases encode as follows:

```
K`cat
K`fish
K`m¶eta-c t
K`m"'`\c
```

Comment: Doesn't work for all inputs. For instance, $$

Comment: @Dadsdy Whoops, I thought I had cleverly golfed nine bytes off my original answer...

Answer (score 2):

## [C++14](https://gcc.gnu.org), 132 + 176 = 308 bytes

```cpp
[](auto&s){auto t=s;s="#include<cstdio>\nint main(){puts(\"";for(auto c:t)s+=c-34?c-92?c-10?s+=c,"":"\\n":"\\\\":"\\\"";s+="\");}";}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVDLTsMwEBQ36q9YGYkmCkEt9ABx3H5IXbWRmxRLjVNl1xeq3vgLLr0gcYH_ga_BToR4HrxrzezsjP34ondbh-EsN1q_znmKtJY6ScYTvnguHDVQgXxyVKU3bw_zRRSgc4z3HUUSBUp-ZqzeunWZay82zVRZYwnqwtgo3u8cYaQ4F1XTdmrQGcWYSJ1eT2Y6vb3yZTyaBeSC84wrZbuqVN-81HNc8VgcuDj0Wd5PTgX79IXcNEhtWdRTxnyELENzXy6JUYkU9QC1xm4AY7ZngyrCWLBBR-jGEeQ5YChDZYeCsUFbkmst4GXYE_nZA2NfTworvrnAtrQgYRSE4ZpI6Hy5LogHnx9gZfDuL1orS0Wq4R9BrfhwpZQOzK_Mfs5H6z_keOz7Bw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 91 + 216 = 307 bytes

```go
import."fmt"
func f(s string){Printf(`package main
import."fmt"
func main(){Print(%q)}`,s)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6FjejM3ML8otK9JTSckuUuNJK85IV0jSKFYpLijLz0jWrA4BUSZpGArJOLkwtIGENqGoN1ULN2gSdYs1aqBVZSEoUqrk40zSUkhNLlDS5OMHqc_I0lEAcoHBaZnEGNvHcmLySRN1kBayacmOU1BNiYpKBXKiNCxZAaAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 49 + 55 = 104 bytes

```
import strutils
proc m[S](s:S):S="echo "&s.escape
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY9BCsIwEEX3OcUQQdtFRXdScOEZurSCIaRt0GlKZorexU1B3Hofb2Noo4Kbz-cxf_7M7d5aHIZHz1W2ea0tds4zEPue7ZlE550G3BeHhPIizYutNLpxIOe0NKRVZ2LwOWJMpJRacdBU_EhlqflDKFhlGv4nUS6OpR6hmAEbYtvWwI3iIAbCNbVXSHBx_iSm3NgX7VgUPZbX1S6WfJEsw_5QMF39efsN)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 19 bytes +10+11+16+15 = 71

Chose to count the trailing newline in the score because it's possible to print without it, as per the other answer.

```ruby
$><<"$><<"
p$<.read
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWm1XsbGyUwARXgYqNXlFqYgpEBqpgwbJcJfWEmGQIDwA)

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 23 bytes +9+10+15+14 = 71

Output doesn't include a trailing newline, but the score turned out to be the same anyways because the solution required 4 more bytes.

```ruby
$><<"$><<"+$<.read.dump
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboW21XsbGyUwIS2io1eUWpiil5KaW4BRBaqaMGyXCX1hJhkCA8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes, score 33

```
ＳＵＴ¿ⅉ´Ｕ´Ｔ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMzr6C0JLgEyE7X0NS05grJT0/PSQ0pyszVAPIy0xQ0IoHiChDFSu/3bH2/Z4uSpvX//9FKuTF5qSWJuskKJUqx/3XLcgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｓ
```

Write the input string to the canvas. This is sufficient to generate a program that prints only printable ASCII; the rest is newline handling.

```
ＵＴ
```

Turn off right-padding. (Has no effect if there was no newline in the input.)

```
¿ⅉ
```

If the input contained at least one newline...

```
´Ｕ´Ｔ
```

... output the command to turn off right-padding.

The test cases encode as follows:

```
cat

fish

m
eta-c tＵＴ

m"'`\c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@XK7UkUTdZoeT9nq3v92z5/x8A) (Third test case only; the others are trivial.)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 24 + 30 = 54 bytes

```powershell
% *ce "'" "''"|%{"'$_'"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7BasMwDD3XXyGEOzXdMnYO5FTWU6GH7raNxPW8ppsTB0dlh6bfnikUmj4Q4uk9PakNfy52lfN@0G0Mh2jqDnIga5iegL6PXSUd67Jhk1pglGGNROWHJeiHOSytAySUIuznZyRdEF4GbcOX27jmwJXEvagpvId1iK/GVul2/@Msw1nN7t2POeji@UrUjFaiZCSWQkg6Qghe5Qz04uZN8M5A2xO3Jx4XH2DxvrPx2PLeB/v7mWWr6Aw72UwSicpvKBtUF4VvgY2H8SPw05npwwSHfw)

Input comes through the pipeline.
`% *ce "'" "''"` - `%` is an alias for the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet, which takes the input string, and runs the string's method "Replace()" (the only one matching "*ce") against it, replacing all single quotes with a double single quote.
This is then piped further to `%{"'$_'"}`; again ForEach-Object, but this time invoking the scriptblock, which simply takes the input string, and wraps it in single quotes; output is implicit.
In PowerShell, anything inside a string enclosed in single quotes is taken verbatim, so no need to worry about escaping anything, except for the single quotes.

As an alternative, a Here-String `@'<LF>...<LF>'@` could be used, which would remove the need to escape even the single quotes:

```powershell
%{"@'`n$_`n'@"}
```

This is only 15 bytes instead of 24, but the output has 6 additional characters per test case instead of 2, and would come to a total of 60 bytes.
In the TIO above, the code can just be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score: 28 (3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) + 25 output sum)

```
"“ÿ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f6VHDnMP7///PVVJPiEkGAA)

The outputs for the four test cases are:

```
Input:      cat
Output (4): “cat

Input:      fish
Output (5): “fish

Input:      """m
            ta-c t""" (multiline input)
Output (9): “m
            ta-c t

Input:      m"'`\c
Output (7): “m"'`\c
```

**Explanation:**

```python
"    "# Push the following string:
 “    #  Regular dictionary quote for the output program
  ÿ   #  String interpolation, which is automatically replaced with the (implicit) input
      # (after which the result is output implicitly - with trailing newline)
```

If there is no trailing `"` or `“`, 05AB1E outputs everything after it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle), 104 (program) + 48 + 82 + 175 + 175 (outputs) = score 584

```
'0.<_.<.>i,S)#..\_//222*3'/."-S:2'*)<.L-3',o\.><#.(,o.""<._.......j)2<>(<#,,o@o+0"@#.,#,o'"........^oo",
```

[Try it in the online interpreter!](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/?i=m%0Ata-c#%270.%3C_.%3C.%3Ei%2CS)%23..%5C_%2F%2F222*3%27%2F.%22-S%3A2%27*)%3C.L-3%27%2Co%5C.%3E%3C%23.(%2Co.%22%22%3C._.......j)2%3C%3E(%3C%23%2C%2Co%40o%2B0%22%40%23.%2C%23%2Co%27%22........%5Eoo%22%2C)

The score is kinda terrible because the output is quadratic in the size of the input. This program:

1. Collects the input and keeps track of length

   ```
                '
               0
              < _
             < . > i
            , S ) # .
             \ _ /
   ```
2. Computes `triangular(3n) - 3n - 2`, the amount of NOPs needed to put the work all on the bottom row of the output program

   ```
                   / 2
          2 2 * 3 ' /
           - S : 2 ' * )
   ```
3. Outputs a leading `\` to redirect the IP to the bottom row, all the filler NOPs, and the "end program" instruction

   ```
         "
        <   L - 3 ' , o \
         > < # . ( , o . "
      " <   _
                       , o @
   ```
4. Repeats the input in a format that Trilangle can understand it. This relies on implementation-defined behavior; it works in my reference interpreter as of v1.6.2.

   ```
     j ) 2 < > ( < # ,
    o + 0 " @ # . , # , o ' "
                   ^ o o " , .
   ```